# How would I edit Vagrantfile so that Vagrant knows to get the .box file from my host?

Tags: vagrant

I'm setting up a development environment with Vagrant. In provisioning a base box, how would I edit `Vagrantfile` so that Vagrant knows to get the .box file from my host?

I've followed the instructions from [Sitepoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/vagrantfile-explained-setting-provisioning-shell/) on how to configure the `Vagrantfile` so that Vagrant has the instructions it needs to provision the base box. But my base box file is located on my computer!

I assume it's also possible to instruct Vagrant to load the base box file from my computer instead of a url (Vagrant Cloud or DropBox) The line of code in question is below.

It specifies the name of the hosted base box file hosted on Vagran Cloud:

```
config.vm.box = "primalskill/ubuntu-trusty64"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set these properties in your `Vagrantfile` to specify a URL:

```
config.vm.box = "centos7"
config.vm.box_url = "http://myserver.mydom.om/centos7"
```

If it's a local file to your system where' you running `vagrant`:

```
config.vm.box = "centos7"
config.vm.box_url = "file:///tmp/centos7"
```

If you're on Windows:

```
config.vm.box = "centos7"
config.vm.box_url = "file:///C:/tmp/centos7"
```